# CLR throws InvalidProgramException

Tags: .net, f#, clr

I am trying to create a `ByRefLike` struct `Context` which contains multiple `ByRefLike` structs. When there is only a single field, the program works. When there are more than 1, the program throws an `InvalidProgramException`.

Why does it throw an error and is it possible to overcome it?

```ml
open System
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
open FSharp.NativeInterop
#nowarn "9" // Pointers are cool

let inline stackalloc<'a when 'a: unmanaged> (length: int): Span<'a> =
    let p = NativePtr.stackalloc<'a> length |> NativePtr.toVoidPtr
    Span<'a>(p, length)


[<Struct; IsByRefLike>]
type StackStack<'T>(values: Span<'T>) =
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable private _count : int
    
    member s.Push v =
        if s._count < values.Length then
            values[s._count] <- v
            s._count <- s._count + 1
        else
            failwith "Exceeded capacity of StackStack"
        
    member s.Pop () =
        if s._count > 0 then
            s._count <- s._count - 1
            values[s._count]
        else
            failwith "Empty StackStack"
            
    member s.Count = s._count

    
module StackStack =
    
    let inline create capacity =
        let values = stackalloc<_> capacity
        StackStack values

[<Struct; IsByRefLike>]
type Context =
    {
        mutable Stack1 : StackStack<int>
        // If you comment out the line below, the program will run just fine
        mutable Stack2 : StackStack<int>
        // Other fields go here
    }

module Context =

    let inline create capacity =
        {
            Stack1 = StackStack.create capacity
            // If you comment out the line below, the program will run just fine
            Stack2 = StackStack.create capacity
        }


let test () =

    printfn "State"

    let mutable c = Context.create 10
    c.Stack1.Push 1
    c.Stack1.Push 2
    c.Stack1.Push 3

    while c.Stack1.Count > 0 do
        let next = c.Stack1.Pop()
        printfn $"NextValue: {next}"

test ()
```

Comment: I can't find source of problem, ILVerify isn't much helpful, but I guess it happens because F# aggressively optimizes `let x = expr in x` into `expr`, which leads `StackStack` to be kept in evaluation stack, instead of be stored into local variable, which happens with C# code. It's the only thing that I can find. Think it's better to be tested with raw IL and be sent to [dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) repo as bug

Comment: Well, I've tested it by decompiling program to IL and recompiling it from scratch with storing `StackStack` into local variables before creating `Context` and it works (at least doesn't throw InvalidProgramException), so it's definitely something wrong with runtime's handling of byref. Tested on net6

Comment: Issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/73102

Comment: Thank you. This info helped me figure out how to work around the F# compiler to accomplish what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

For the curious, this is how you would accomplish this in F#.

> **NOTE** This is highly, non-idiomatic F# code but I'm dealing with a high-performance scenario.

```ml
open System
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
open FSharp.NativeInterop
#nowarn "9" // Pointers are cool

let inline stackalloc<'a when 'a: unmanaged> (length: int): Span<'a> =
    let p = NativePtr.stackalloc<'a> length |> NativePtr.toVoidPtr
    Span<'a>(p, length)


[<Struct; IsByRefLike>]
type StackStack<'T>(values: Span<'T>) =
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable private _count : int
    
    member s.Push v =
        if s._count < values.Length then
            values[s._count] <- v
            s._count <- s._count + 1
        else
            failwith "Exceeded capacity of StackStack"
        
    member s.Pop () =
        if s._count > 0 then
            s._count <- s._count - 1
            values[s._count]
        else
            failwith "Empty StackStack"
            
    member s.Count = s._count

    
module StackStack =
    
    let inline create capacity =
        let values = stackalloc<_> capacity
        StackStack values

[<Struct; IsByRefLike>]
type Context =
        val mutable Stack1 : StackStack<int>
        val mutable Stack2 : StackStack<int>
        new (stack1, stack2) =
            { Stack1 = stack1; Stack2 = stack2 }

module Context =

    let inline create capacity =
        let stack1 = StackStack.create capacity
        let stack2 = StackStack.create capacity
        Context (stack1, stack2)


let test () =

    printfn "State"

    let mutable c = Context.create 10
    c.Stack1.Push 1
    c.Stack1.Push 2
    c.Stack1.Push 3

    while c.Stack1.Count > 0 do
        let next = c.Stack1.Pop()
        printfn $"NextValue: {next}"

test ()
```